# Asymptotics of the number of minimal strongly connected digraphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

Is anything known about the number of minimal strongly connected digraphs on $n$ labeled nodes? (``Minimal’’ meaning that on the deletion of any arc, strong connectivity is lost.) Some values are given in sequence [A130768](https://oeis.org/A130768) at OEIS.org, but no generating function or asymptotic estimate is given. This feels like something that should be known, being a natural digraph analog of the famous question of the number of trees on $n$ labeled vertices.

**Context**: I’m preparing lectures, and while I was writing notes on a theorem of the form “the following 5 statements are equivalent”, it occurred to me that it would be nice to discuss in class the question: “in how many ways can one show that $n$ statements are equivalent, without any redundant implications in the proof?”.

Comment: There is a webpage devoted to these digraphs, http://jglopez.etsisi.upm.es/MSC_Digraphs_Page/ but a quick look through it suggests that the asymptotics really are not known.